# table component for webform

Tags: 6, entities, webforms

is there any module to add "table component" to webform?
I want to have a button to add a row to that table.it means that the rows count not limited and is added number of  user want.

sorry,my English not good ;)

Answer (score 2):

There's now a [table component](http://drupal.org/project/webform_table_element) module for webform, take a look to it.